# What is the REGEX for: FULLSTOP + no or not + chocolate

Tags: mysql

I want to use RLIKE in MySQL to select cells that have the word "chocolate".
However there must also be the word "no" or "not" between the word "chocolate" and the **last** fullstop that occurred **before** "chocolate".

In otherwirds what is the regular expresson for

```
.%chocolate
```

where % **must** contain 'not' or 'no'
AND % **must not** contain another fullstop

For example all 3 of the following sentences are acceptable:

```
Charlie likes fruits. Charlie does not like chocolate. 

Today is a good day.  I do not feel like eating chocolate or apples.

1. No chocolate is allowed.
```

The following 3 examples are rejected:

```
Andy is not a child... He loves chocolate. 

Today is not a good day. I have no money. I want to eat chocolate and orange. 

1. Chocolate is good for you.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `REGEX` but this could be an alternative:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT val,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'.',2) AS valCheck
FROM mytable
HAVING valCheck LIKE '%chocolate%') A
WHERE CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(valCheck,'chocolate',1) LIKE '%no %' THEN 1
         WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(valCheck,'chocolate',1) LIKE '%not %' THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END=1;
```

Your 3 condition got me thinking so, I guess using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `HAVING` to filter the first value after a single full-stop that have the word `chocolate` in it. Namely this:

```
SELECT val,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'.',2) AS valCheck
FROM mytable
HAVING valCheck LIKE '%chocolate%'
```

Will return the following:

| val | valCheck |
| --- | --- |
| Charlie likes fruits. Charlie does not like chocolate. | Charlie likes fruits. Charlie does not like chocolate |
| Today is a good day. I do not feel like eating chocolate or apples. | Today is a good day. I do not feel like eating chocolate or apples |
| 1. No chocolate is allowed. | 1. No chocolate is allowed |
| 1. Chocolate is good for you. | 1. Chocolate is good for you |

Notice that `valCheck` returns exactly as it's original value because it's a match against the two conditions being placed. The next step is to make that as a subquery and filter the value with the 3rd condition; must have `no` or `not` after the full-stop but before the string `chocolate`. Here I'm using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` again but this time with `CASE` expression and using the string `chocolate` as the delimiter.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2ddefb4a67bc31d473d89fdbe3881f4)